# Is signature same as hash value encrypted with the private key in openssl?

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature, openssl

Computing the signature of *hello.txt* file which has the text `hello` in it, here is done in two steps:

```
openssl sha1 -binary -out hash hello.txt
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey private.key -in hash -out signed -pkeyopt digest:sha1
```

First we'll get the *digest value* in the *hash* file, then this file is signed getting the **signed** file, this file is the signature of *hello.txt*
But, when i try to *encrypt* this *hash* file;

```
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -inkey private.key -in hash -out encrypted
```

The file **encrypted** is different from **signed**. Why these two files are differents? if the answer to my question is no, why not?

Answer (score 3):

See PKCS1 now at [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017); encryption and signature are different things -- and for all PKC not just RSA, publickey encrypts or verifies, privatekey decrypts or signs (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)).

**`openssl pkeyutl -encrypt`** (and also the older `rsautl` for RSA) accepts a privatekey *file* (which contains the publickey as well, i.e. the keypair), a publickey file, or a certificate file -- see options `-pubin -certin` on the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html) -- but it ***uses* the publickey** -- see the descriptions of `-sign -encrypt -decrypt` (although `-verify[recover]` fails to mention it).

See also [my long list of Qs explaining that signature is not encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/can-openssl-decrypt-the-encrypted-signature-in-an-amazon-alexa-request-to-a-web#159289)

Also, encryption is randomized; if you encrypt twice you get different results, so you couldn't determine correctness just by comparing the files anyway. *Some* signatures are randomized, including RSA-PSS, but not RSA-PKCS1v1_5.

Comment: Thank's, how does the recipient of the message find out whatever it is inside the signature?, I guess the publickey must be applied somehow, the signature (`signed` file) cannot be decrypted in openssl, the command `-decrypt` only accepts the privatekey not the publickey

Comment: @user2495207: for most signature schemes (including common RSA ones) the signed data cannot be recovered from the signature; both data and signature must be sent. There are many ways of doing this; e.g. PGP 3 decades ago pioneered 'clear signing' where the signature is encoded and can only be processed with PGP software, but the data is plain and can be read with any software, with the limitation that when you can't or don't verify the signature you risk forgery or tampering. See https://xkcd.com/1181/ for a humorous take on this. ...

Comment: ... For RSA only it is possible to design signatures 'with recovery' (rather than 'with appendix') which recover a _limited_ amount of data that must meet strong and specialized constraints. This is used in some specific cases where data needs to be minimized and can be strictly controlled, such as EMV payment-card (smartcard) transactions.

Answer (score 2):

No, encryption of a hash of a message is never the same as a signature. The closest it gets is  with RSA with PKCS#1v1.5 padding, where signing is related to decryption of a padded hash of a message.

There is *no such thing* as encrypting with a private key. Private keys can sign or decrypt, by definition. In systems other than RSA it's mathematically invalid, in RSA it's semantically invalid.